# How do set IdentityResult?

Tags: asp.net-identity, usermanager

I'm in a situation where I need to validate a new (or updating) users' email address using some more complex rules.

I thought of using the User store that goes into the user manager but where and how does the IdentityResult get constructed?

Do I just throw an exception and that's it? Or is there some extra validation mechanism?

Answer (score 13):

`IdentityResult` takes an `IEnumerable<String>` in the constructor:

```
public IdentityResult(IEnumerable<string> errors)
```

These are the errors that will be passed back to the calling code.

Alternatively you can call this  method:

```
var identityResult = IdentityResult.Failed("First error", "Second validation error");
```

This will be identical to the calling the constructor with list of strings.

Comment: Looks like .NET Core doesn't accept an error list in the constructor anymore. Alternativelly you can call `IdentityResult.Failed(msgs.ToArray())`.

Answer (score 3):

.NETCore has changed things. So to return a failed result where you assign your own errors you would have to create a fully qualified `IdentityError` instance for each error you want to pass.

Let's say for example you have the following errors and you want to returl a failed result with those errors:

```
var errors1 = "Your password is incorrect";
var errors2 = "Your email is not recognized";
```

To proceed and return a failed address for with these errors, you would do the following:

```
var result = IdentityResult.Failed(
   new IdentityError[] {
      new IdentityError{
         Code = "0001",
         Description = error1
      },
      new IdentityError{
         Code = "0002",
         Description = error2
      }
   }
);
```

Basically what's happeneing here is that the new `Failed` method of the `IdentityResult` expects `params` as `IdentityError[]`. Obviously, if you had many errors you'd create an `IdentityError[]` variable and then put all your errors in and then pass it to your `Failed` method.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this :

```
var errorMessage = new IdentityError
                {
                    Description = "error message"
                };

                result = 
                    IdentityResult.Failed(errorMessage);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.